# 7 wonders Babel and Armada

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-babel

When is the exact release date for Babel? It seems to be some time in November, but It was due to come out in Feb, so why did it drag on?

Also what happened to Armada, which was tested by some players two years ago: 
http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/851200/7-wonders-armada-playtest-summary

Comment: My FLGS got Babel in on Wednesday... So assuming there isn't a run on the the first printing, you should be able to get your hands on a copy fairly easily now.

Comment: @aslum cannot find them on sale from a UK seller. slightly unwilling to pay another 12 euros for shipping...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [7 Wonders article in the French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_Wonders#Extensions_.C3.A0_venir),

- *Armada* has no release date, and
- *Babel* is supposed to be released in the first half of October 2014.

In his private blog, Antoine Bauza (the author of *7 Wonders*) published an [image of the *Babel* box](http://www.antoinebauza.fr/?p=3494), with the caption

> OCTOBER 2014 (Essen)

This refers to the [*SPIEL* tradefair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiel), which takes place from 2014-10-16 to 2014-10-19 in Essen, Germany. So it’s likely that the extension will be released then.